# Случайная выборка записей mysql

Tags: mysql, случайные-числа, mysql-faq

Как можно организовать случайный выбор записей из таблицы, посредством одного запроса?

P.S.: Имеется таблица статей, а также сводная таблица (статьи на тему), со ссылкой на первую таблицу. Нужно добавить в сводную таблицу N записей, указателей на статьи случайным образом.

Можно ли как-то случайно выбирать строки из таблицы в запросе?

Comment: Я начинающий, но в моем случае на сайте photo-master.net нужно было выбрать 5 случайных заметок с той же категории.
Так у меня скрипт помещает все id постов данной категории в масив, потом уже по тому масиву идет цыкл for который проходит 5 раз, за каждый раз выберает произвольное число с помощью функции rand() и вытаскивает с базы запись и выводит на экран.

Comment: Вот [ссылко](http://webdev.cz.cc/mysql/4-optimization/11-mysql-optimizaciya-order-by-rand), почитайте, весьма интересно расписано, заодно для опыта пригодиться. Вкратце: там приводится пример оптимизации `ORDER BY RAND`

Comment: @АлександрКобылянский это плохая практика. вы выбираете все записи а потом из них случайным образом выбираете 5шт. а если у вас будет несколько миллионов ? зачем выгружать с БД инфо о миллионах записей если вам нужно только 5?

Comment: @Dex одним запросом (выборка случайных 5 записей):  

    `select * from 
    ( select * from some_table order by rand)
    where rownum  <= 5;`

Comment: @jmu, это ад, а не запрос. В качестве объяснения и наказания себе сделайте таблицу на пару млн записей на локалке и запустите запрос) Вы в память всю таблицу сложите.

Comment: @jmu если уж на то пошло, то более простой вариант и менее затратный

`select * from some_table order by rand() limit 1,5;`

а вы делаете: 

`select * (select * from some_table order by rand()) limit 1,5;`

Где логика?

Comment: @Dex логика: моей задачей было дать человеку пищу для умственного труда, а не возможность получить профит за чужой счет :)

Comment: А вам критично именно одним запросом? Просто если таблица большая, то `order by rand` будет тормозить, но на хабре на эту тему есть статья где проблема решена хранимой процедурой. Идея, вкратце, состоит в том что выбираются 5 случайных номеров строк из таблицы, и потом уже запросом читаются только эти конкретные строки.

Answer (score 12):

Если размер таблицы статей `articles` не велик, можно отсортировать записи в случайном порядке, например, при помощи конструкции `ORDER BY RAND()`. Вставить записи в сводную таблицу `theme_articles` можно при помощи запроса `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

```
INSERT INTO
  theme_articles
SELECT
  *
FROM
  articles
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

К сожалению, у конструкции `ORDER BY RAND()` печальная слава, так как чаще всего она означает сортировку данных на жестком диске. Уменьшить вероятность этого события можно уменьшив размер промежуточной таблицы. Даже если `EXPLAIN` сообщает о сортировке в файле, при небольшом размере таблицы, высока вероятность, что сортировка пройдет все-таки в оперативной памяти (особенно, если значение директивы `tmp_table_size` достаточно высоко - несколько десятков мегабайт).

В любом случае имеет смысл сортировать в случайном порядке не всю таблицу, а лишь первичные ключи - это уменьшит размер сортируемой промежуточной таблицы

```
INSERT INTO
  theme_articles
SELECT
  m.*
FROM
  (SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2) AS r
LEFT JOIN
  articles AS m
USING(id);
```

Такой вариант подойдет уже для средних таблиц. Если же у вас имеется возможность выбрать первичные ключи в случайном порядке вне СУБД - это самый идеальный вариант в случае гигантских таблиц (достигающих гигабайтных размеров). Как правило, в таких случаях СУБД используют совместно с каким-нибудь NoSQL-решением, полностью расположенным в оперативной памяти. Можно попробовать извлечь идентификаторы случайных статей из него (что заведомо быстрее MySQL завязанной на транзакции и жесткий диск) и воспользоваться первым запросом, задействовав для выбора статей конструкцию `IN`

```
INSERT INTO
  theme_articles
SELECT
  *
FROM
  articles
WHERE
  id IN (252, 1024);
```

Запросы выше предполагают, что структура таблиц идентичная, первичный ключ имеет имя `id`, а количество вставляемых случайных записей равно 2.

Answer (score 5):

Данная задача сводится к получению N случайных ID статей. Когда они получены на основе них выбирается любая информация по статьям и вставляется в целевую таблицу.

Если таблица не очень большая, то случайные ID выбираются простым запросом (тут и далее таблицу со статьями будем называть `randTest` и выбирать N=10 записей):

```
select ID from randTest
 order by rand()
 limit 10
```

Решение способно дать нужное количество статей со случайными, хорошо распределенными, значениями ID. К сожалению данное решение вынуждено выбрать все существующие ID из индекса и отсортировать их случайным образом. При большом количестве записей, удовлетворяющих условиям поиска статей в исходной таблице это накладно. На тестовых данных в 1.2 миллиона записей данный запрос отработал за `0.601009` сек. Если работа разовая, этим можно пренебречь. Но что, если подобный запрос надо выполнять часто ?

Следующим, по распространенности способом получать случайные записи является запрос заранее получающий нужное случайное число и ищущий запись с ID равную или большую вычисленному:

```
select id
  from randTest,
       (select ceil(min_id+rand()*id_cnt) rnd
          from (select max(id)-min(id) id_cnt,min(id) min_id from randTest) A
       ) N
 where id>=N.rnd
 limit 1
```

Полученный запрос предусматривает, что в таблице ID могут начинаться не с 1 и нумерация может идти с "дырками". Например, в моей тестовой таблице минимальный ID=1, максимальный 2322674, при том что записей всего 1245191, для чистоты эксперимента оставлены дырки в нумерации более 100к ID подряд и между всеми существующими ID оставлен зазор в 5-30 номеров, что эмулирует таблицу с большим удаленным блоком старых данных. Столь сложная вложенность подзапросов к сожалению потребовалась из за того, что MySQL некорректно воспринимал непосредственное `id>=(rand()*min()...)` и выдавал только записи из первых тысяч.

Но у данного запроса два существенных ограничения - он может выдавать только по одной записи и при многократном использовании он будет выдавать ID находящиеся сразу за большими "дырками" в данных гораздо чаще, чем другие значения. Т.к. если у нас нет записей от 0 до 100к, то любое значение rand() меньшее 100к будет давать запись с id 100001.

Попробуем решить эти две проблемы. Во первых, что бы была возможность генерировать N случайных значений нам нужна таблица с N записей. Назовем ее `seqnum`, ее наполнение не имеет роли, например там будут записи с единственным полем со значениям 1,2,3,... Во вторых, нам надо решать проблему дыр. Для этого мы перестанем искать записи *большие* найденного числа, а будем брать записи *строго равные* ему. Правда в таком случае часть случайных чисел не дадут записей на выходе. Эту проблему мы решим просто увеличив количество получаемых чисел с хорошим запасом, так что добавим в seqnum скажем 8*N записей.

```
select id
  from randTest,
       (select ceil(min_id+rand()*id_cnt) rnd
          from seqnum,
               (select max(id)-min(id) id_cnt,min(id) min_id from randTest) N
       ) A
 where id=rnd
 limit 10
```

Запрос дает стабильно 10 случайных ID за `0.001446` сек. Что в 400 раз быстрее `order by rand()` на 1.2M записей. Обращаю внимание, что получение max(id) и min(id) в MySQL работают практически мгновенно, т.к. получаются непосредственно из начала и конца индекса и их прямое применение в запросе вполне оправдано. Данный метод применим к боле менее нормально наполненным таблицам. Если же у вас в таблице на 100 записей задействовано 100000 ID, то для получения 1 случайной записи потребуется перепробовать более 1000 случайных чисел. В таких случаях может помочь только генерация дополнительной таблицы в которой с разрозненными ID основной таблицы будут сопоставлены подряд идущие номера записей.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE cond = '0' and
      id > FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table))
LIMIT 1
```

Ну и JOIN не забыть.

Answer (score 3):

Если записей не много, то `ORDER BY RAND` в помощь. Иначе, выбирайте все в массив, `array_shuffle()` и потом берите с него 5 элементов.

Comment: легче тогда ORDER BY RAND

Comment: @Андрюша `ORDER BY RAND` экспоненциально замедляется при росте базы данных

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Пускай есть таблица:

```
Create table articles  (id number, txt text)
```

где `id` - это ИД статьи, а `articles` это сама статья.
Можно попробовать упорядочивать статьи по хэшу `MD5(ID||to_char(SYSDATE(), 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))`. Благодаря уникальности времени, хэши каждый раз должны получатся разные. 
То есть получается что-то в духе:

```
select ID from articles order by MD5(ID||to_char(SYSDATE(), 'yyyymmddhh24miss')) LIMIT 2;
```

Вместо мд5 можно использовать любую хэш функцию, в том числе и достаточно простую. Не берусь сказать, как быстро будет работать подобное решение. Это просто способ взглянуть на проблему с другой стороны, не используя `Order by Rand()`

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что для этого нужно будет каждый раз считать хэш каждой записи в таблице?

Comment: А что если сгенерить нужное количество случайных номеров и вытащить записи с этими номерами?

Comment: order by md5(...) боюсь будет еще дольше чем order by rand(). Причем даже если предположить, что md5 сама по себе быстрее чем rand() то размер ключа для сортировки все равно больше и потребует больше места в области сортировки

Comment: @Nick Volynkin хэш будет собираться каждый раз да.

Comment: @Mike тогда вместо МД5 можно реализовать и свою функцию, причем можно достаточно простую, чтобы получать небольшой набор данных. Только распределение тогда будет больше хромать. Я не утверждаю, что это решение быстрее `RAND`, я говорю, что можно его его попробовать. У самого нет времени проверить)

Comment: А чем своя функция будет лучше обычной rand() ?

Comment: Я не знаю, что делает Rand, возможно простой хеш получать быстрее. В любом случае, добавление функции похоже вызывает полностью создание нового набора в памяти с добавлением колонки, которую придется сортировать, и главная проблема похоже именно в этом. Так что похоже такое решение ощутимого прироста скорости не даст, даже если будет работать быстрее rand.

Comment: Проверил, md5 проигрывает по скорости rand() в 1.3 раза.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

Пускай есть таблица:

```
Create table articles  (id number, txt text, num number)
```

де `id` - это ИД статьи, `articles` это сама статья, `num` - это номер строки по порядку(от `0` до `n` без пропусков). По полю `num` строим уникальный индекс.
Задумка такова: получить порядковый номер случайно строки и выбрать ее.
Таким образом случайная статья будет селектиться так:

```
select * from articles where num in (select round(rand()*count(1), 0) from articles)
```

Из недостатков, если надо много случайных статей, то запрос придется выполнять несколько раз. В теории при таком подходе удастся избежать тяжелых сортировок с использованием `Rand`.

Развивая тему, можно добавить пару настроечных таблиц. Первая будет знать, сколько всего статей в `Articles`, чтобы не пробегать весь набор данных каждый раз. Например инкрементально обновлять значение тригером при добавлении новой строки. А вторая таблица будет содержать необходимое кол-во строк для получения нужного набора из рандомных статей.
Пусть есть таблица `count_articles`  с одной строкой и колонкой `cnt` содержащей кол-во строк в `articles` и таблица `table2` содержащая столько строк, сколько надо случайных статей. 
Тогда запрос 10 случайных статей может выглядеть примерно так:

```
select * from articles where num in (select round(rand()*c.cnt, 0) from count_articles cnt join table2 on 1=1)
```

Comment: Вы бы проверяли запросы на той СУБД для которой предлагаете решение. MySQL _не позволяет_ использовать limit внутри предложения `in`. Кроме того в жизни редко встречаются таблицы с нумерацией с 1 без дыр. И min/max по индексу работают мгновенно, на любой СУБД (в отличие от count())

Comment: @Mike С `limit` не знал, спасибо. Про нумерацию, я заранее написал, что надо колонку, которая будет отвечать за нумерацию без дырок. Эта задача не кажется невыполнимой.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy ну самый развернутый мой ответ по этой теме вот прямо тут, в этом же вопросе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516026/194569 других не помню

Answer (score -2):

Почему минусы - обясннте что в ответе неправильно. Только не нужно писать "`все не правильно`". Конкретно что не так? Может операции с массивами очень реурсоемкие.

---

*Сегодня утром почему-то меня "пробило" на решение этой "проблемы".*

1. Загрузить ВСЕ идСтрок в массив. В моем решении это, наверное, единственный недостаток, потому что если таблица состоит из многих миллиардов строк, то ОП не хватит для массива.

   1.1 Выборку делаем НЕ в цикле! Простой селект select capid from tbl;
2. Делаем массиву array_shufle().
3. И после этого $rnd_rows=array_slice($mass, 0, КоличесвтоРндСтрок)

   3.1 КоличествоРндСтрок может быть аргументом функции, написанной вами, для получения случайных строк.
4. Проверки на количество нужных рндЗаписей, и на кол-во элементов в массиве (т е строк в таблице) сами сможете реалиовать.
5. Описал решение "проблемы" без примеров кода, для того чтобы вы сами внесли нечто свое в реализацию этой "очень сложной проблемы" %:)).
6. Если массив очень огромный, незабываем  делать ему unset().

---

Зачем столько мучаться, придумывать какие-то многострочные (многостраничные) хитрые запросы? Даже на жабре *(в том числе и на этом ресурсе решения нет. Если бы оно было то не было бы извращений с многострочными непонятными запросами)* такого `ПРОСТОГО` решения нет. Там есть всякие извращения. Но я уже давно не читаю Хабр - там очень мало адекватного материала).

7. Но если  вы пишете блокнот на sql, и используете только sql, то даное решение вам не поможет.
8. Не забываем голосовать за ответ. У меня есть некоторые вопросы, но задавать я их уже не могу.

Comment: Вообще вопрос был про mysql. suffle по сути тот же order by rand только выполненный на клиенте а не в БД. это потребует 1. поднять записи с диска (ладно, уговорили, только первичный индекс), 2. передать его весь на клиента (а это мегабайты, и БД предполагается не на той же машине где клиент, да даже если на той же все равно тормоза и лишняя нагрузка). 3. выполнить order by rand средствами клиента.

Comment: Уж если на то пошло и надо действительно быстро получать и без извражений, гораздо проще в отдельном индексированном поле вести подобие ID только сплошное, безразрывное. с "зашиванием дыр" при удалении записей триггерами. после этого просто генерим нужное кол-во целых чисел не превышающих кол-во записей

Comment: :( теперь понятно

Comment: хотя если надо "совсем быстро" и не грузить БД я бы вообще выделил сегмент разделяемой памяти, в него сложил список id и брал случайные ячейки из него. ну и отдельный процесс который при изменениях в БД будет удалять/доабвлять id в него. А клиентские процессы просто будут его цеплять на чтение и брать id

Comment: или патч написать к MySQL, который order by rand с лимитом выполнит особым образом ;) в общем не стандартных клиентских решений на самом деле можно много придумать ...

Comment: @Mike, по простоте мое решение, на сегодняшнем уровне моих не знаний, для меня более понятно, чем многострочные запросы, которые я до сихх пор не совсем понимаю.