# имеетли смысл использование stmt-query к даным которые никоим образом не

Tags: sql, select

имеет ли смысл использование stmt-query к данным которые никоим образом не касаются GET POST запросов? То есть пользователь никогда не запишет в стобец "ид" и пользовательского селекта к этим данным не будет никогда.

Например нужно считать ВСЕ "ид" (автоинкремент) из тбл и загрузить их в массив для последующего выбора случайного элемента массива.

---

Думаю, что тут можно без stmt обойтись.

Comment: запросы с привязанными переменными могут выполнятся быстрее, чем с значениями подставленными в сам текст. т.к. при подстановке в текст БД каждый раз перекомпилирует запрос, а когда текст запроса ни на символ не меняется БД может использовать план выполнения из кеша. На некоторых БД выполнение множества запросов с разными значениями непосредственно в тексте приводят к переполнению SQL-кеша и сильной деградации производительности системы. Если вы конечно об том спрашиваете (абсолютно не ясно что такое stmt query). И кстати случайную запись можно получить непосредственно SQL-запросом из БД

Comment: mysqli_prepare,   
mysqli_stmt_bind_param
mysqli_stmt_execute($rawdata)
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($rawdata, $capid);
мysqli_stmt_fetch($rawdata)
...

Comment: "случайную запись можно получить непосредственно SQL-запросом из БД" - не вполне понял.
"На некоторых БД выполнение множества запросов с разными значениями непосредственно в тексте приводят к переполнению SQL-кеша и сильной деградации производительности " - вы хотели написать "в текстовом формате"? Неподготовленные запросы каждый раз разбираются и аж потом идут на выполнение  - и этим они снижают производительность.(?)

Вообще то я спрашивал с точки зрения безопасности. Но вы написали что "можно получить случайную запись" - я этого пока что не понял.

Comment: А bind_result там вам зачем ? prepare -> bind -> execute -> fetch. Или если пользоваться PDO вместо mysqli то даже проще prepare->execute(с параметрами)->fetch. Они не просто разбираются, каждый когда либо выполненный запрос еще и в системных таблицах может сохранятся, что ведет к росту таблиц SQL-кеша. С точки зрения безопасности различий нет. Особенно если данные чисто цифровые. Но bind параметров придуман далеко не для безопасности. безопасность - побочный эффект :)

Comment: А вообще с SQL надо работать так что бы тянуть из БД только те записи, которые реально необходимы. Вытаскивать на клиента массив ВСЕХ ID ради получения нескольких случайных элементов неразумно. Есть масса других способов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-mysql/516026#516026

Comment: cпс, гляну, но в моем конкретном случае это капча вопросы. их там и 100 шт не будет. Дело в том что можно сначала получить рандомное значение а потом вытянуть строку. НО ид будут с "провалами", то есть: 1 2 3 5 8 10 11 12 15 16 20 25 26 27.

Comment: Ну если их там всего 100, то `select * from tab order by rand() limit 1` даст отличный результат (это для MySQL, для других БД вместо rand() надо будет что нибудь другое придумать)

Comment: читаю то что вы указали - сложновато для меня, (копипастом я не пользуюсь. Я же непонимаю как это рабртает).  Ссылка в закладках - пригодится для выбора случайных пользователей или постов, комментариев. Да, я mySQL.

Comment: rand() дает случайное число. таким образом order by rand() сортирует записи в случайном порядке, limit 1 берет одну первую запись после случайной сортировки

Comment: та это я уже понял. а вот над этим  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-mysql/516026#516026 надо подумать

Comment: Mike, для выбора 1 рнд записи из тбл с дырками или без оных, я решил делать два запроса. сначала получить значения ИД мин и макс . Потом ИЗ ЭТОГО диапазона получить рнд. и в  запросе на получение одной строки ... вот пример кода: select * from tbl where id<=$rnd limit 1; Считаю что лучше 2 запроса за 0 секунд, чем 1 запрос за 2 секуды. По другому написать вам не могу. та и не уверен6 прочтете ли вы это.

Comment: Странно что он у вас за 2 сек. тот вариант, что я приводил последним в том ответе (ссылка выше) он отрабатывал моментально. если 2 сек. значит что то не совсем так как у меня, там шаг влево шаг вправо и у оптимизатора крыша едет

Comment: 2  сек - это я образно выразился. ваш код раюотает http://itmages.ru/image/view/4273129/51f98efd но я все-таки не буду его использовать, он для меня не очень понятен. Хотя ... незн., может украду ваш пример.

Comment: и еще одно: то что сам сделал - понимаешь на 101%. для меня мой вариант более простой и абсолютно понятен.