# 0 или 1 или 2 или 3 строки на одно rnd значение. ПОЧЕМУ?

Tags: sql, select, выборка

Я мучаюсь с выборкой случйных строк из таблицы. Практикуюсь на основании статьи http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Но запрос возвращает от 0 до Х строк. Хотя в теории должен вернуть одну строку.

Таблица на 3 млн строк.БЕЗ дырок.

```
mysql> describe trnd;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| svar  | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Оптимизированный селект для получения рандомного числа:
mysql> select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd));
+------------------------------------------+
| ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)) |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                  2245350 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from trnd where id=(select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)));
+---------+------------+
| id      | svar       |
+---------+------------+
|  929379 | Q123456789 |
| 1353830 | Q123456789 |
| 2420265 | Q123456789 |
+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (1.39 sec)
mysql> 

еще ДВА ТАКИХ ЖЕ селекта:
mysql> select * from trnd where id=(select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)));

+---------+------------+

| id      | svar       |
+---------+------------+
|  637559 | Q123456789 |
| 2388566 | Q123456789 |
+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (1.45 sec)

mysql> select * from trnd where id=(select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)));
Empty set (1.42 sec)

mysql>
```

### ПОЧЕМУ ТАК???

Я хочу понять как правильно делать энтую оптимизацию, потому и мучаюсь. А тут вдруг откуда-то появилось странное поведение sql.

В статье есть ошибки (скорее опечатки, а не ошибки)- посчитайте количество скобок в

```
EXPLAIN SELECT name  FROM random  WHERE id = (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *     (SELECT MAX(id) FROM random))
```

> NO, NO, NO. Don't go this way.

Это я вижу в статье, но почему возврат от 0 до 5 или 8 строк?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-mysql/516026#516026

Comment: Вы почитали тот мой ответ, там даже в тексте написано, что приходится делать дополнительную вложенность, иначе оптимизатор MySQL глючит. И заодно есть возможность получить сразу 3 записи (последним приведенным там методом). Ответ на ПОЧЕМУ - вот так есть, обращайтесь к разработчикам MySQL потому как выглядит как глюк самого движка

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-mysql/516026#516026 "Столь сложная вложенность подзапросов к сожалению потребовалась из за того, что MySQL некорректно воспринимал непосредственное id>=(rand()*min()...) и выдавал только записи из первых тысяч." -?

Comment: Ага, и просто подзапрос в where, в том виде, что у вас в вопросе давал так же кривой результат

Comment: если вы о select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)) то выдавал ОДННО  значение. щас перепроверю. Проверил - выдает только одну строку. Потому я и создал такой вопрос. НА 1 рнд от 0 до 8 строк.

Answer (score 2):

По времени выполнения запроса больше похоже, что mysql переписывает подзапрос в correlated subquery, который вычисляется для каждой строки таблицы: для какого id повезло совпасть с рандомом - те строки и вернулись. Вообще, этот баг оптимизатора старый, вроде бы в 5.5 или 5.6 его исправляли уже. Вы на какой версии проверяете?

Во всяком случае, известен обходной манёвр для этого бага: переписать в join:

```
select * from trnd join (
    select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)) as id
) r using(id);
```

Comment: Server version: 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: в статье так и написано. и я это еще вчера протестировал, но %:(( не совсем понимаю как это работает. Ну работает и хр с ним. Буду применять это решение для тбл без дырок, но интересно хотя бы на половину понять как несколько записей вытаскивать

А . дальше хочу с дырявыми тбл разобраться

Answer (score 0):

msi, посмотрите на

```
mysql> select * from trnd order by rand() limit 1;
+--------+------------+
| id     | svar       |
+--------+------------+
| 213131 | Q123456789 |
+--------+------------+
1 row in set (5.84 sec)
```

и на

```
mysql>  select * from trnd join (select ceil(rand()* (select max(id) from trnd)) as id) as r2 using (id);
+---------+------------+
| id      | svar       |
+---------+------------+
| 2006868 | Q123456789 |
+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Поле ответа служит только для ответа на поставленный вопрос. Пожалуйста [не пишите слова благодарности и/или новые вопросы и/или уточнения к своему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) в поле ответа на http://ru.stackoverflow.com. Вам стоит внести правку в свой вопрос, добавив данные подробности, а не публиковать их как ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Если вам нужно выбрать строку случайным образом, то почему бы не сделать так:

```
select * from trnd order by rand() limit 1;
```

Comment: ??? ПОТОМУ ЧТО ТБЛ НА 3 МЛН ЗАПИСЕЙ! (Хоть и тестовая) И я как раз мучаюсь, чтобы не использовать убийцу серверов - констуркцию: ... order by rand();

Comment: Я выше пример привел.