# вывод случайной записи из таблицы (mysql, php)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, база-данных

Совсем недавно начал изучать веб-программирование, и пытаюсь сразу применять знания на практике, но не всегда бывает гладко, поэтому образовался следующий вопрос (прошу прощения если он окажется очень примитивным):

программа должна выводить случайную цитату из таблицы, а при нажатии на кнопку, цитата должна переключатся на следующую случайную цитату. Все бы ничего, но часто происходит так, что одна и та же цитата, повторяется по 2-3 раза, и приходится несколько раз подряд нажимать на кнопку, для того чтобы она переключилась.

Код страницы (из комментария):

```
<?php
    include_once 'db_connection.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        include_once 'header.php'; 
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM men_challange ORDER BY RAND() ");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row['value'];
    ?>

    <form>
        <button>пропустить-&gt;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Выполненно" onclick="alert('Молодец!');javascript:window.location='index‌​.php'">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Может код покажите который у вас так делает ? А что бы не повторялась - единственный путь помнить несколько последних что бы их собственно не выбирать. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-mysql

Comment: @Mike 

<?php include_once 'db_connection.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<?php

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM men_challange ORDER BY RAND() ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['value'];

 ?>
 <form>
  <button>пропустить-></button>
   <input type="button" value="Выполненно" onclick="alert('Молодец!');javascript:window.location='index.php'"/>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: нужно как то в массив это добавить и в нем перемешать, но я пока не понимаю как(

Comment: массив где то хранить придется между вызовами - это крайне не удобно. проще сохранить ID записей которые уже были показаны и  запрос чуть доделать `select * from man_challange WHERE ID not in(1,2,3) order by rand()` собственно все - запрос выберет только строки за исключением указанных (1,2,3). А где хранить ... в куках например или в даных сессии (если есть)

Comment: Опомнитесь! **`ORDER BY RAND()` - зло**, для каждой строки будет расчитано случайное значение и по ним (в памяти/свопе) будет отсортировано.. это создаст сильную нагрузку на базу. Правильней будет сначала сделать `SELECT COUNT(id)`, потом сделать `$rand=mt_rand(0,$count-1);` а затем уже выбрать 1 запись через `ORDER BY id LIMIT $rand, 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include_once 'header.php'; 
        include_once 'db_connection.php';
```

mysql - устаревшее расширение и больше не поддерживается. Используйте mysqli либо PDO

```
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Так как нам нужно только поле value, то использовать * - излишне

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM men_challange");
```

Заполняем массив цитатами

```
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            $values[] = $row[0];
        }
```

Перемешиваем

```
        shuffle($values);
    ?>
    <span id='cite'></span>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
         var container = document.getElementById('cite');
```

Создаем массив с цитатами в контексте JavaScript

```
         var cites = <?php echo json_encode($values)?>;
         var index = 0;
```

Функция замены цитаты в блоке `<span id='cite'></span>`

```
         function changeCite(){
             container.innerHTML = cites[index];
             index++;
```

Если цитаты закончились - возвращаемся к самой первой

```
             if(index==cites.length)index=0;
         }
```

Один раз запускаем при загрузке страницы

```
         changeCite();
    </script>
```

`form` в данном случае не нужен. Перезагрузка страницы при каждом нажатии тоже не нужна.

```
    <button onclick='changeCite();'>пропустить-&gt;</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу два варианта:

1. делать всего один запрос к серверу, при котором в страницу грузится целиком большой массив цитат. Перемешивается случайно на сервере, или уже в странице [с помощью Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/556876). По нажатию на кнопку страница не грузится, а только выводит следующую цитату из массива.
2. «помнить» `id` предыдущих N выпавших цитат, и следующую страницу загружать POST-запросом, в котором передавать список N `id` ранее выпавших цитат. Их использовать в запросе для исключения (как предложил в комментариях [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)).

Поскольку вопрос про PHP, приложу примерный код для второго:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $used = [];
        $where = '';
        if( isset($_POST['used']) && is_array($_POST['used'])) {
            $used = array_map( $_POST['used'], function( $el){ return intval($el);})
            $where = sprintf(' WHERE id NOT IN (%s) ', implode(',', $used));
        }

        include_once 'db_connection.php';
        include_once 'header.php'; 
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, value FROM men_challange " . $where . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row['value']; // вывод цитаты

        array_push( $used, intval( $row['id']));
        $used = array_slice( $used, -5); // оставляем не более 5 последних id
    ?>

    <form method="post">
        <?php
            foreach($used AS $id) {
                printf( '<input type="hidden" name="used[]" value="%d">', $id );
            }
        ?>
        <button type="submit">ещё цитат!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```