# Как можно оптимизировать простой SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Как можно оптимальнее выбрать первые 5 записей после 1000000?

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1000000,5`

Я решил сыграть в "лотерею" и выбрать первые 5 записей, но если это что то изменит могу добавить сортировку по айдихе.
ID - индексированное поле!

**Задача не является реальной**

Comment: Без ORDER BY это не запрос, а лотерея. А с ORDER BY - просто нужен соотв. индекс.

Comment: это неправильный подход. Нужно создать индекс, и выбитать по индексированому столбцу - тогда будет быстрее.

Comment: Секционировать таблицу, например, по диапазону ключей или функции какой.

Comment: @Lyth что значит секционировать, по диапазону ключей ?

Comment: @Akina подправил вопрос

Comment: @nick_n_a У первичного ключа и так есть индекс, или Вы хотите сказать если я поменяю `SELECT *` на  `SELECT ID` что то изменится?

Comment: Вам ничего в данном случае не поможет. Смещение в миллион записей должно быть отработано, т.е. этот миллион должен быть прочитан и выброшен. Надо разбираться зачем вам вообще понадобилось такое смещение в лимите. Что бы была скорость, надо сделать так, что бы некое условие фильтровало записи в части where и по индексу. например кешировать в отдельной таблице с каких примерно id начинать искать миллионную

Comment: @Mike Да смещение должно быть отработанно, но выбор 1000005 записей происходит на порядок быстрее нежели выбор 5ти

Comment: Может вы при выборе миллиона не задаете order by (недаром вы его позже приписали, да еще с ошибками, такой запрос не отработает) или еще что. Миллион записей занимает минимум несколько мегабайт, что бы вытащить их на клиента уже будут приличные затраты времени, без учета времени самой БД, так что если это быстрее, чем выбор 5, значит на выполнение еще что то влияет. А может у вас там на самом деле не select * из одной таблицы ... А в зависимости от условий в лимите может меняться план выполнения ... Вообще бесполезно сравнивать скорость чего либо не выполнив по обоим запросам explain

Comment: @Mike Да, Вы правы `OREDER BY` не использую, и спасибо подправил запрос, добавил не посмотрев.

Comment: Вы бы хоть немного расшифровали "задача не является реальной". Если вы говорите что выбор миллиона быстрее, чем выбор по смещению, значит есть на чем проверять и задача более чем реальна. Так что сравнивайте explain ваших реальных запросов с смещением, без этого невозможно понять как именно БД выполняет запрос и почему она может тормозить в одном случае больше чем в другом. Может вам надо в реальном запросе изобразить пару условий чуть по другому и ей станет значительно легче ...

Comment: @JVic изменится если выбор будет по индексированому полю `where ID between 1000000 and 1000005`

Comment: @JVic И кстати, может откроете тайну, зачем вы используете limit без order by, вы же не можете гарантировать какие данные будут получены, а значит вам нужны некие случайные данные. А для получения случайных данных можно придумать массу других, быстрых способов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516026/194569

Comment: @Mike Да могу, задали вопрос на собеседовании, и смог предложить только то что здесь и перечисляли.

Comment: хм. и их не устроили предложения избавляться от offset в лимите любыми способами ... странно. может при такой странной постановке задачи они конечно хотели увидеть `select ID` с таким же лимитом в подзапросе IN, он быстрее отработает, чем `select *` т.к. пойдет по индексу, вместо данных, а потом уже опять же по индексу и `*` подберется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Краткий ответ:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 1000000,5
        ) q
JOIN    table t
ON      t.id = q.id
```

Более подробный ответ:
Прямой запрос с такими параметрами читает все записи в таблице с 1 по 1000005, но возвращает только последние 5, из-за избыточных чтений вы получаете долгий запрос. Чтобы его ускорить, вам нужно "подсказать" движку, что читать с 1 по 1000005 нужно не всю таблицу, а только индекс, выбрать из него 5 последних прочитанных записей, и потом присоединить значения из всей таблицы.

Совсем полный ответ (на английском) есть в этой статье:
https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/