# Mysql: как выбрать рандомную запись?

Tags: mysql

Подобный вопрос задавали не один раз, но работающий способ я так и не нашел.

У меня есть таблица mysql, мне нужно выбрать из нее одну запись, с условием "param = 1". Таблица очень большая, выборка нужна максимально быстрая, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE param = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;" не подходит.

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Comment: Таблица, может, и большая... а сколько это "в граммах"? А также - сколько в тех же граммах записей соответствует заданному условию отбора? И имеется ли индекс, соответствующий этому условию?

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант для идеальной таблицы, в которой нет пропущенных (удаленных) id.
На бекенде можно сгенерировать 10 случайных чисел в нужном диапазоне и получать записи по ним. `WHERE id in (...)`

Второй вариант для не идеальной таблицы, но  позволяет получить лишь одну запись. Тот же рандом на бекенде, но ограниченный числом записей. А дальше `OFFSET {random_number} LIMIT 1`

UPD:
Хотя, говорят большой offset тоже медленно работает. Но, предполагаю что все равно быстрее `ORDER BY rand()`

UPD 2:
Нашел такой вариант реализации:

```
SELECT f.id FROM files f
    JOIN ( SELECT RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM files) AS max_id ) AS m
    WHERE f.id >= m.max_id
    ORDER BY f.id ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

По [ссылке](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+order+by+rand%28%29) подробности и сравнение с `ORDER BY RAND()`

А [здесь](http://hudson.su/2010/09/16/mysql-optimizaciya-order-by-rand/) большая и подробная статья с анализом быстродействия трех вариантов

Comment: *Есть вариант для идеальной таблицы, в которой нет пропущенных (удаленных) id* И хрена ли с него толку? отбор-то идёт ни разу не по ID...

Comment: offset что бы посчитать смещение вынужден выбрать _все_ предшествующие записи и выбросывать их. Так что по скорости работы это будет катастрофой

Comment: @Akina Прекрасно работает отбор по ID, если ID были случайно генерированы. Но, как и сказал, только в идеальном случае, что бывает крайне редко

Comment: @Mike при order by вообще временная таблица создается, и >1M записей счет уходит на минуты

Comment: Нашел еще варианты, добавил в ответ

Comment: @НикитаУмнов Варианты лучше прямо тут на SO искать. Вот большое исследование на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-mysql