# mysqli запрос после заполнения базы стал обрабатываться до 15 секунд. Как оптимизировать запрос?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT t1.sait 
FROM spisok_saitov_android AS t1 
LEFT JOIN  saiti_userov_v_rabote_android AS t2 ON 
        t1.sait = t2.sait_v_rabote  
        AND CURDATE() < t2.date_work 
        AND t2.user_name = '$username'  
WHERE t2.date_work IS NULL 
     AND t1.metka_progulki = '$metka_progulki'  
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

В таблице `spisok_saitov_android`, строк 500
А вот в таблице `saiti_userov_v_rabote_android` когда число строк достигло отметки 95000 строк, то и начались проблемы.

Как мне изменить запрос чтобы избавиться от такой супер длительной обработки запроса?

Comment: сами то как думаете, сортировка по случайному значению в принципе может быть быстрой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Случайная выборка записей mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-mysql)

Comment: Хотя возможно у вас проблема не в сортировке, раз в основной таблице всего 500 записей. А по второй таблице вы проверяете отсутствие записи. Смотрите план выполнения запроса (explain). Возможно у вас нет подходящего для данного запроса индекса на таблице saiti_userov_v_rabote_android (идеальным был бы user_name, sait_v_rabote, date_work; первые два поля можно переставить местами)

Comment: А можете написать как будет выглядеть в таком случае запрос?

Comment: Думаю, есть смысл попробовать переписать на WHERE NOT EXISTS...

Comment: А можете написать как будет выглядеть в таком случае запрос?

Comment: В каком именно случае ? Если дело в не правильном индексе, то запрос менять вообще не нужно. В любом случае надо начать с просмотра плана выполнения, что бы понять в чем именно тормоза

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```sql
SELECT t1.sait 
FROM spisok_saitov_android AS t1 
WHERE t1.metka_progulki = '$metka_progulki'  
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM saiti_userov_v_rabote_android AS t2 
                   WHERE t1.sait = t2.sait_v_rabote  
                     AND t2.user_name = '$username'  
                     AND CURDATE() < t2.date_work )
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```