# Оптимизация ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql, случайные-числа

Наткнулся на статью [https://ruhighload.com/Оптимизация+order+by+rand%28%29](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+order+by+rand%28%29) Сделал по аналогии. Но данный пример работает странно: элемент повторяется через пару обновлений, хотя в базе 100 тыс записей. Подскажите, действенный метод оптимизации `rand()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Случайная выборка записей mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-mysql)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 4):

Статья - бред голимый. Ибо требует кучи оговорок, стыдливо опущенных.

`ORDER BY RAND()` обеспечивает равновероятный выбор любой записи (в рамках равномерности генератора, конечно), тогда как описанная методика делает эту вероятность пропорциональной количеству пропущенных (отсутствующих) последовательных значений ID после элемента (или перед - смотря какой частный подход использовать) - например, если в таблице два элемента с ID 1 и 1000000, то при использовании описанного в статье запроса у первого практически нет шансов вернуться.

Методика могла бы заработать, но для этого нужно гарантировать, что последовательность имеющихся ID как минимум непрерывна (и начинается с единицы). В большинстве случаев это означает перенумерацию записей в запросе. Да, это несложно сделать - если версия СУБД поддерживает CTE и ROW_NUMBER(). Но в любом случае это уже немножко другие время и ресурсы.

Я уж не говорю о том, что ID далеко не всегда имеет числовой тип - скажем, GUID последнее время достаточно (и зачастую небезосновательно) популярны. К ним описанную в статье методику вообще не приложить.

Comment: т.е., ничего лучше, чем ```ORDER BY RAND()``` нет?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis А это от задачи зависит. И от того, что именно поддерживается сервером. На восьмой версии для решения задачи сортировка не нужна.