# Не выводится информация БД. mysqli. запрос на рандомный вывод

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

имеется запрос на выборку из БД рандомных статей. Подключение настроено верно, вывод и значения колонок таблицы тоже верные. Но на выходе все равно ничего не показывается.

Полагаю, что проблема в самом sql запросе. Можно ли такой запрос использовать? и где в нем ошибка?
помогите пожалуйста.(

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "data";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("нет " . $conn->connect_error);
} $sql = "
SET @random = ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `news`));
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM news LIMIT ', @random, ', 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<a href='page?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['text']." <br><i><b>".$row['name']."</b></i><br><br>
</a>";
 }
} 
else {
 echo "пусто";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: после выполнения запроса проверяйте на наличие ошибок и главное, если ошибки есть выводите сообщения о них, что бы понимать что происходит. А не гадать есть в запросе ошибки или нет.

Comment: дело в том, что в phpmyadmin(если вставить напрямую в поле sql) этот запрос нормально проходит и отдает результат.

Comment: И если уж использовать такой подход к выводу случайной записи, то я бы не извращался полностью в sql с динамическим запросом, а получил случайное число на php и сделал бы запрос с нужным лимитом, просто подставив полученное значение в текст.

Comment: Если он проходит в phpmyadmin это не значит что он отработает из php. на сколько я понимаю драйвер не дает выполнять более 1 предложения за раз. Но это только предположение и что бы узнать так это или нет надо выводить ошибки. Гадание на кофейной гуще "а где же тут ошибка и есть ли она" малоэффективно. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: пишет, ошибка в синтаксисе You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM news LIMIT ', @random, ', 3'); PREPARE stmt...' at line 2   но честно говоря, даже не понимаю как написать этот запрос sql иначе...((

Comment: Получите одним запросом количество записей, а вторым вытащите случайную запись

Comment: @DanKasper Ну да, то что я и подозревал. ошибка на второй строке. драйвер php не умеет передавать составные запросы. Так что единственный вариант при текущем подходе - вытащить в php количество записей, сгенерить случайное число и собрать запрос с limit в php. Или используйте другие методы получения случайной записи, выполняющиеся за 1 запрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516026/194569

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

[PHP SQL code online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/a5f0c72707993f8dfd2e375ab270a803/php/php8/1342805436a7e284b6e9d17df5039629/)