# Как сделать выборку рандомной записи из базы в MySql без ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql, order-by

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать следующий запрос SQL(конкретно надо сделать решение без ORDER BY RAND(), так как он очень медленный)

```
SELECT user_id,ht_number,q_number FROM ht_user_p2 
JOIN questions2 ON questions2.q2_id = ht_user_p2.q_id
WHERE questions2.q2_public=1 
AND ht_user_p2.user_ball IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Эти варианты смотрели: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: Да, но к сожалению я новичок в этом, и мне тяжело это применить к моему запросу

Comment: [CrazyElif](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf), помогите пожалуйста, по работе очень нужно

Comment: Или эти ответы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21904/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-mysql/516026#516026